# OpenCV to find coordinates of the smooth and sharp tips of a droplet shape

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, geometry, coordinates

I use OpenCV in Python to track fish in aquarium. When recorded with a camera located above the aquarium tank, fish look like a droplet on the video, especially after applying grayscale, thresholding and contour detection in OpenCV.

[image: droplet shape]

I'm now wondering if it would be possible to find the coordinates of the smooth and sharp tips of this ~droplet shape (basically the top and the bottom tip of the white shape on the picture included in this post), which would correspond to the head and tail of the fish. These coordinates would help to record where the head and the tail of the fish are in the video, and how the fish is oriented. I can't think of an easy solution to do this, but maybe someone here has an idea?

Comment: Perhaps try getting the bounding box of the drop. Then find the white (non-zero) pixels in the top row and the bottom row (see np.nonzero). If more than one, then get middle one

Comment: moments can express key qualities of this shape.